# Angular Material Sidebar - How do I trigger draw toggle in another component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

The button is in the navbar, which is in a different component to the sidebar.
My layout look something like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport="true"
    [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

On navbar, I have this button:

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()">
  <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the sidebar as a child component in the navbar as `@ViewChild('drawer') drawer: ElementRef;` or create the toggle class in your sidebar component and use `@ViewChild(SidebarComponent) child: SidebarComponent;` in your navbar component and toggle it with the `this.child.'class_in_sidebar'`